# How to extract numbers from string containing numbers+characters into an array in Ruby?

Tags: arrays, ruby, regex, string

I have string that contains integers and characters and I need to extract all numbers in array, for example:

```
str = "achance123for84faramir3toshowhis98quality"
#=> [123, 84, 3, 98] #Desired output
```

I am having trouble grouping them together. I have tried:

```
str.split('').select {|el| el.match(/[\d]+.*/)}
#=> ["1", "2", "3", "8", "4", "3", "9", "8"]

str.split('').select {|el| el.match(/[\d]+[\D]+/)}
#=> []
```

How can I maintain the grouping for all integers and list them in array? Assume it will contain *only* numbers and characters (a-z). No whitespace/ non-word characters. All will be lowercased.

*(they don't have to be converted to integer. I am just having problem coming up with the regex to separate them in groups. If there is a solution without Regex, that'd be awesome too!)*

Comment: Do they need to be in order? Can they be negative?

Comment: @PrestonM, they don't need to be in order :)

Comment: Might be of interest `str.split(/\D+/) #=> ["", "123", "84", "3", "98"]`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try using `String#scan`, like this:

```
str.scan(/\d+/)
#=> ["123", "84", "3", "98"]
```

If you want integers instead of strings, just add `map` to it:

```
str.scan(/\d+/).map(&:to_i)
#=> [123, 84, 3, 98]
```

Comment: your firstpart work well but secondpare is showing error, please see http://rubyfiddle.com/riddles/8bdef

Comment: @artgb That's odd, something to do with _rubyfiddle_, testing in IRB and with [repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/HomelySelfassuredFoxhound) works fine.

Comment: Both _rubyfiddle_ and _repl.it_ run ruby snippets online (no local installation needed), IRB (_interactive ruby_) is a ruby interpreter installed with ruby and will used to run snippets on your local machine.

Comment: Probably something to do with rubyfiddles ruby version? str.scan(/\d+/).map{|s| s.to_i} does the job btw